# c++ changing implicit conversion from double to int

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have code which has a lot of conversions from double to int . The code can be seen as

```
double n = 5.78;
int d = n; // double implicitly converted to a int
```

The implicit conversion from double to int is that of a truncation which means 5.78 will be saved as 5 . However it has been decided to change this behavior with custom rounding off .

One approach to such problem would be to have your own DOUBLE and INT data types and use conversion operators but alas my code is big and I am not allowed to do much changes . Another approach i thought of was to add 0.5 in each of the numbers but alas the code is big and i was changing too much .

What can be a simple approach to change double to int conversion behaviour which impact the whole code.

Comment: you could use a `#define int INT` and provide your own conversions. Not claiming that this is nice, but given your constraints it might be a way

Comment: Some compilers have hidden options that allow you to redefine built-in operators (like `operator+(int, int)` or `operator int(double)`.  I wouldn't recommend using them, though, because they're liable to cause more trouble than they prevent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use uniform initialization syntax to forbid narrowing conversions:

```
double a;
int b{a}; // error
```

If you don't want that, you can use [`std::round`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) function (or its sisters `std::ceil`/`std::floor`/`std::trunc`):

```
int b = std::round(a);
```

---

If you want minimal diff changes, here's what you can do. Please note, though, ***that this is a bad solution*** (if it can be named that), and much more likely leaving you crashing and burning due to undefined behavior than actually solving real problems.

Define your custom `Int` type that handles conversions the way you want it to:

```
class MyInt
{
//...
};
```

then evilly replace each occurence of `int` with `MyInt` with the help of preprocessor black magic:

```
#define int MyInt
```

Problems:

- if you accidentally change definitions in the standard library - you're in the UB-land
- if you change the return type of `main` - you're in the UB-land
- if you change the definition of a function but not it's forward declarations - you're in the UB/linker error land. Or in the silently-calling-different-overload-land.
- probably more.

Comment: This would require me to change code at all the places where such conversions are happening (which is a lot) and I am not allowed to make a lot of code changes.

Comment: @MAG short of `#define int MyCustomInt` I don't see how you could make that a small change in a diff.

Comment: @krzaq Amazing how you named your class `myInt` at the same exact moment as I submitted my answer, where I suggested this solution :)

Comment: @space_voyager I have time machine left over from the *Learn C++ in 21 days* course

Comment: Add to problem list: the poor sap who is the next developer who has to read your code is going to have no idea what you've done...

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int myConvert (double rhs)
{
    int answer = (int)rhs; //do something fancier here to meet your needs
    return answer;
}

int main()
{
    double n = 5.78;
    int d = myConvert(n);
    cout << "d = " << d << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can make `myConvert` as fancy as you want. Otherwise, you could define your own class for `int` (e.g. `myInt` class) and overload the `=` operator to do the right conversion.